# How to solve Unknown column alignment in KaTeX?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and I would like to write this:

```
p_i(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}
    1, & \text{if}\ y=i \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{array}
```

in a ipynb file but I get:
ParseError: KaTex parse error: Unknown column alignment 1 at position ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post but I think I have your answer.  If you add {c} for center column alignment after the {array} tag it should fix it.

```
p_i(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
    1, & \text{if}\ y=i \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{array}
```